# create multiple temporary tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to run a raw SQL queries, it makes multiple temporary tables. this works when running it in the database but not in code.

```
public function test(){
            $sql ='
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS SELECT SUM(11) ;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_3 AS SELECT SUM(11);
  select test.* FROM  test ;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test, test_3;
            ';
    
            $sth = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
    
}


SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_3 AS SELECT SUM(11) AS  bar' at line 2 (SQL:  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS SELECT SUM(11) AS  foo; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_3 AS SELECT SUM(11) AS  bar;        )
```

however, making just one temporary table works.

```
public function testJustOne($user){
        $sql ='
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS SELECT SUM(11) AS  foo;
        ';

        $sth = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));

}
```

there must be a way of just running the query as is.

Comment: Two or more query statements are not supported. Why do you have to run two at once?

Comment: it's more than 2, I just want it to run the statement that works as a query if that make science

Answer (score 1):

This is an unprepared query that executes multiple statements in laravel.

> \Illuminate\Database\Connection::unprepared

```php
$sql ='
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS SELECT SUM(11) ;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_3 AS SELECT SUM(11);
select test.* FROM  test ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test, test_3;
';
$result = DB::unprepared($sql);
```

#### MySQL general query log

It's just like running it from the MySQL console.

```
Query   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS SELECT SUM(11) ;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_3 AS SELECT SUM(11);
select test.* FROM  test ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test, test_3
```

#### Error exception

You can only detect errors for the first query.
The following example returns `$result = true` without error.

```php
$sql ='
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS SELECT SUM(11) ;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_3 AS SELECT SUM(11);
select test.* FROM  test ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test, test_3;

select error_force_test() from dual;
';
$result = DB::unprepared($sql);
```

#### Security risk

Since it is not a prepared query, be careful of sql injection when receiving input values.

Comment: unprepared just returns true, how do I get the result?

Comment: The only way to get results while executing more than multiple statements is to make `stored procedure` or `function` in MySQL.